# Nesting Shortcodes in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nested, shortcode

First off, I have searched for an answer, but everything I have found refers me to the Codex, which, quite simply, might as well be written in "Greek".  I have just started using Wordpress and I do NOT know a lick about PHP, so the Codex is just a bunch of gobblity-gook.  I thought this should be simple, maybe it just can't be done, but here we go...

I have a shortcode (which I found by googling) which hides content on my Wordpress site if you are NOT logged in. [member] Must be logged in to see this. [/member]  That works great.

Now, I have added a database using Participant Database plug-in and want to display a list of people from that database using their shortcode... {pdb_list]  This too works just fine, BUT....

What I need to do is "[member] [pdb_list] [/member]".  Not everyone who visits the site needs to be logged in, but to see the list they MUST be logged in.  PLEASE help, but don't just say read the codex (Greek to me), or say use "do_shortcode()", that answer is also indecipherable given my experience.

This seems it should be simple, but I can't figure it out... T.I.A.!

Comment: The search function here on [so] is your friend. Search by tag and order the results by votes: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bwordpress%5d%20shortcode%20inside%20shortcode

Comment: I saw that question, but I don't UNDERSTAND it.  And the example from the Codex, as I stated, is like "Greek" to me.

Comment: Well, you have to try the code and see for yourself... using `do_shortcode($content)` **is** the solution... as stated here, on the Codex and the duplicate question...

Answer (score 1):

[Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API#Nested_Shortcodes) says:

> The shortcode parser correctly deals with nested shortcode macros, provided their handler functions support it by recursively calling [do_shortcode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) :

In plain English, if you want to use nested shortcodes, you must translate them in outer shortcode.

```
function member_shortcode($atts, $content = "") {

    if ($content) {

        $content = do_shortcode("[{$content}]");

    }
```

Comment: I have read the Codex, but I don't get it.  What does "recursively" mean.  This is like a foreign language (to me).  I don't write code.  How do I "insert" my two shortcodes in the "plain English above???  [pdb_list] needs to be "wrapped" in [member] ... [/member]

Comment: recursively means to check for shortcodes within shortcodes.You must write **some** code. Find the member shortcode and make sure it checks for attributes and content in definition like `($atts, $content = "")` then add the three lines  of if statement in my answer.

Comment: Ok, I have the function for member..                                            
 function member_check_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() && !is_null( $content ) && !is_feed() )
  return $content;
 return '';
}       But where do I put the code you wrote above?

Comment: before your `return $content;`

Comment: Thank you!  I admit, I still can't "read" this code and understand it and there is now another issue (the nested shortcode call appears as html text when the member is NOT logged in), but I can live with that until I can learn more about WordPress, shortcodes and PHP.  Mille grazie to you, WDMBG!